# TriggerIO - RevMobAds

Tags: ios, plugins, trigger.io

I've created a native plugin, implemented RevMob SDK, tested on simulator, build the plugin, upload to trigger.io.
When I select the application to use the plugin the builder said:
Undefined symbols for arhitecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RevMobAds", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in bigmagerevmob.a(bigmagerevmob_API.o)
ls: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Framework http://sdk.revmob.com/, I tried to inport it with the build, but cant. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your built module doesn't include the RevMobAds library code.

Documentation on including libraries is here: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/external_libraries.html#3rd-party-librariesframeworks

Looking at the RevMob SDK file you will want to copy `RevMobAds.framework/Versions/A/RevMobAds` directly into your ForgeModule xcode project, and make sure it is included in the ForgeModule target.